# echo null with json encode in php

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am using php code to echo some mysql items with json encode by the below command:

```
echo json_encode($Bcore).",".json_encode($Brow).",".json_encode($Bcol).",".json_encode($Bdir).",".json_encode($Bid).",".json_encode($Bname).",".json_encode($Bi).",".json_encode($Bii).",".json_encode($Biii).",".json_encode($Fcore).",".json_encode($Frow).",".json_encode($Fcol).",".json_encode($Fdir).",".json_encode($Fid).",".json_encode($Fname).",".json_encode($Fi).",".json_encode($Fii).",".json_encode($Fiii);
```

this results the below input when some entries in the database are null:

```
"x","y","z",null,null,null ... etc
```

is there anyway to print null in jsonencode format to be like that:

```
"x","y","z","","",""
```

as I need the output to be double quoted for every entry.

Comment: Why don't you just JSON encode the array instead of individual entries?

Comment: The problem is, that `null` and `""` are different values. So, you will have to make them `""` before you `json_encode` them.

Comment: DB null and PHP null are different.  Only PHP null will encode that way.

Comment: thanks, I had to change every null to "" before echo it. it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a replace.

```
if ( is_null($value) ) {
    $value = '';
}
```

There's probably deeper problems with the general approach you are taking. I would go to programmers.stackexchange.com and ask them if there's a better approach to accomplish whatever you're goal is.

Comment: thanks, this works, I used the function for every variable before echoing it.

Comment: @SheriffSaidElahl Thanks, accept if it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Before json_encode() you can use [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) to check value is null or not. If it's null then convert it into " ".